# cygwin not finding find - paths wrong

Tags: windows-7, cygwin

Somehow my installation of `cygwin` went wrong on my `Win7` machine.

When I open a terminal and type `find`, it says

```
Adam@fangorn /usr/bin
$ find .
FIND: Parameter format not correct
```

which apparently means that the Windows find command is executing and not the cygwin one.

I know I can execute it with `/usr/bin/find` but last time I used `cygwin` I'm sure I didn't have to do that.

What do I have to do to make cygwin work for all users?

Reinstall?

ADDED:

```
Adam@fangorn /usr/bin
$ echo $PATH
/cygdrive/c/windows/system32:/cygdrive/c/windows:
    /cygdrive/c/windows/System32/Wbem:
    /cygdrive/c/windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0:
    /cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/ATI Technologies/ATI.ACE/Core-Static:
    /cygdrive/c/Program Files/Intel/WiFi/bin:
    /cygdrive/c/Program Files/Common Files/Intel/WirelessCommon:
    /cygdrive/c/Program Files/Java/jdk1.6.0_26/bin:
    /cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/Smart Projects/IsoBuster:
    /cygdrive/c/PROGRA~2/MICROS~1/Office:
    /usr/bin:
    /cygdrive/c/Program Files/Microsoft SQL Server/110/Tools/Binn:
    /cygdrive/d/dev/apache-maven-3.0.3/bin:
    /cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/Skype/Phone:
    /cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/QuickTime/QTSystem:
    /cygdrive/d/nodejs:
    /cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/DTN/IQFeed:
    /cygdrive/c/Users/Adam/AppData/Roaming/npm
```

ADDED FURTHER:

`/etc/profile` the first non-commented line is `PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:${PATH}"` so it appears something has gone wrong in the start-up scripts execution. ( Thanks @matzeri )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check your PATH variable settings in cygwin.
You must have `/usr/bin` before anything else

`/etc/profile` defines the proper order as 
`PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin${PATH:+:${PATH}}"`.

Check if `/etc/profile` matches `/etc/defaults/etc/profile` ; if not look at the differences and eventually replace it with the default version.

Comment: That makes sense. I added the current `$PATH` to the question. I can fix it manually, but how? Should I create a new `$PATH` declaration in a `.profile` file in my home dir? If I do that, would I have to do it for all users individually?

Comment: thanks but in `/etc/profile` the first non-commented line is `PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:${PATH}"` so it appears something has gone wrong in the start-up scripts execution.

Comment: Are you running a login shell  `bash -l` ?

Comment: Thought I was, but if I run `bash -l` then it comes good and my `$PATH` is correct. I have 2 "cygwin terminal" icons in my start menu and one is pinned to my taskbar, which is the one I have been using. Looking at its properties, it's not the same as the one in the start menu. It must have been foobarred by an upgrade or something. So problem solved! Thanks.